# Image inverse sets are pairwise disjoint given that the sets are pairwise disjoint

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow E$ be a function and for each $C \subseteq E$, let $f^{-1}(C)=\{ x \in \Omega: f(x) \in C\}$, then suppose that sets $C_{i} \subseteq E$ are pairwise disjoint. Now, I want to show that the sets $f^{-1}(C_{i})$ are also pairwise disjoint.

**Defination** : Sets $A_1$, $A_{2}$,.... are (pairwise) disjoint if $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ whenever $i \neq j$.

**Possible answer:**

Let $x\in f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)\Longrightarrow f(x)\in A\cap B$, contradiction

However, I was hoping to make a more appealing argument other than doing it by contradictions, so I was wondering if someone would have a better proof approach.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with proofs by contradiction, and it’s hard to imagine anything much nicer than this very simple, straightforward argument. However, you can avoid proof by contradiction simply by proving the contrapositive, which is, after all, logically equivalent to the desired implication: just show that if the sets $f^{-1}[C_i]$ are not pairwise disjoint, then the sets $C_i$ are not pairwise disjoint. This is of course very nearly identical in its details to the proof by contradiction, but it does not in fact appeal to contradiction in any way.

Comment: The basic fact here is:$$ f^{-1}(A\cap B) = f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$$